# RealList in RealmObject not automatically loaded

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-list

i am having the following issue:

This is the class for `ProjectInfo`

```
public class ProjectInfo extends RealmObject
{
    @Getter @Setter @PrimaryKey private long          projectId;
    @Getter @Setter             RealmList<Submission> submissions;
}
```

And this is the class for `Submission`

```
public class Submission extends RealmObject
{
    @Getter @Setter @PrimaryKey long    id;
    @Getter @Setter             Date    creationDate;

    public Submission() {}

}
```

When i create the objects and save to the realm database, the reference from ProjectInfo to Submission is shown like this in the column

`class_Submission{0,1,2,3}`

This looks right.

But now when i load the projectInfo object with

```
ProjectInfo projectInfo = realm.where(ProjectInfo.class).equalTo("projectId", projectId).findFirst();
```

The projectInfo.submissions == null;

**Do i have to do something special to automatically load references from other tables?**

I am using realm version

`classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.1.1'`

The @Getter and @Setter are from projectLombok.

### UPDATE1

While debugging i see a member called `sumbissionsRealmList` in the `ProjectInfoRealmProxy` class which has the correct values. But they are not written into the `submissions` member. What is the reason?

Comment: you should try to watch the `submissions` field's getter in your debugger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course not. All fields inside a RealmProxy are lazy-loaded. You obtain the list via `getSubmissions()`, which will return the list that contains the proxies of the elements. The fields themselves are just to provide the underlying Realm schema (and to load them with data for unmanaged objects, which Realm uses to populate the underlying Realm when you call `insertOrUpdate` or `copyToRealmOrUpdate`)

But this is all mentioned in the documentation:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging